# Interoperability with Compose and motion layout doesn't scroll?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout

I have a the following layout in a fragment

```
Header Image
====================================
Tab 1.         Tab2.          Tab3.
====================================
Frag A.        Frag B.        Frag C.
```

This fragment has a motion scene that when you scroll up the header image transitions to the regular toolbar. I am trying to migrate the fragment from Tab3 to compose by simply using the xml Compose tag and just doing `setContent` in its fragment

This works but when I try to scroll up on the fragment the motion scene no longer works and only scrolls up and down within its content (sorta like a nested scrollview)

is it possible to still trigger the motion layout so that the fragment move up and behaves as it was before?

Update :

Marked answer as accepted. My xml was also out of whack which I had to remove the SwipeRefreshLayout since this will be managed in compose.

```html
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the modifier of your top content.

```
.nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection())
```

Comment: this seems to work only when scrolling down. Scrolling up doesn't work unless I scroll down and then up, then headers goes back to normal state. would you know what I am missing?

Comment: @Beto Is the coordinator layout a parent of the header and content? It is a common problem for compose to be compatible with a traditional view system in nested scroll behavior. If you replace compose with a scrollable traditional view, will the header work normally?

Comment: And,you can refer to this issue to get helpful information. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174348612

Comment: wow that worked one of the I had to get rid of the Swipe to refresh xml I had, updating question with xml giving issues. Thanks for the help!